# Reply address '' specified by the request is not a valid URL

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have followed the [Azure Active Directory B2C: Sign in by using Azure AD accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom) article but currently receiving an error:

> AADSTS50011: Reply address '' specified by the request is not a valid URL. When logging in with both Azure AD and Azure AD B2C accounts.

I have followed the article through multiple times but have been unable to resolve.    It seems to redirect to the App registration correctly but seems to be an issue with the reply URL of the app registration as if I remove this reply URL I get an error stating that no reply URL is present.

Answer (score 2):

This error:

> AADSTS50011: Reply address '' specified by the request is not a valid
>   URL. Allowed schemes: '*'

Is a bug on the AAD side that hides the real error which is that your reply URLs don't match.
I would double check that the reply URL on the AAD side (the v1 multi-tenant app, not the B2C app) is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/YOURTENANT.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
```

**Make sure to replace YOURTENANT above with your tenant name.**

Also, double check that you are setting:

```
<Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this info!