# Error AADSTS50011 re empty reply address using Azure AD B2C and Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to configure Azure AD B2C to use Azure AD (org-owned) as an IDP using the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom.  I believe I've completed all the steps but when trying log in using an AAD account (using the "Run now endpoint"), after entering the username and password I get the error

> AADSTS50011: Reply address '' specified by the request is not a valid URL. Allowed schemes: 'http,https'

I understand in general what a reply address is, but I don't know where the (apparently empty) reply address is being found.  I verified that the AAD App registration representing AAD B2C has a reply URL defined, and that the B2C Application representing the actual web app has a reply URL defined.  I've also verified that the same B2C tenant allows login through another defined IDP (MSA accounts).

Any suggestions as to where to start looking?

thanks

Martin

Comment: When you are going through the Authentication Process, what Reply URL are you sending as the User logins in? Note `redirect_uri` is [one of the properties you need to send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code), and likely that is where you are making a mistake if you validated your app object has all the right properties.

Comment: Does [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919300/reply-address-specified-by-the-request-is-not-a-valid-url) help you out?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett - I don't think so, I've verified both the items mentioned in that answer.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi - I am initiating the authentication by navigating to the "Run now endpoint" provided within the AAD B2C console for my AAD-specific policy; the URL includes a 'redirect_uri' parameter (pointing to localhost) whose value appears to match a reply URL defined for an app registered in the B2C tenant.

Comment: Can you share the **exact** parameter being sent? Can you also share the **exact** configuration you have set up for Reply URL?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi - The URL I'm using to invoke the authn for my custom policy is   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/MBHB2C.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_signup_signin_AAD&client_id=b79e01a8-31d9-4561-9f2f-90fd7ec4d67d&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44316&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login`  

In B2C, in the Properties of one of my applications, the Reply URL is   
`https://localhost:44316`  

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply URL that you input when you register an app in your Azure AD tenant (not Azure AD B2C tenant) is case sensitive. Make sure everything is lowercase.

Comment: So, this worked; but as far as I can tell I was consistent in using uppercase in the name of my tenant (just the custom part, not the onmicrosoft.com part) everywhere, so does this mean that the reply URL in the app registration in Azure AD just has to be all lower case, no matter what the case of the actual tenant name is?